How to delete the lower half of the crop box of a pdf in python?
I have a weired pdf file that has the crop box twice the height of the media box, which caused the waterprint to be printed outside of the media box and therefore invisible.
So I'm trying to make the waterprint visible by deleting the lower half of the crop box so the crop box and media box would have the same size. However, I failed to do despite by the tutorials on Google.

Why is it not a good idea? The lowerhalf of the crop box is basically useless, it won't make a difference if they are gone. And the upper half is exacally the same as the whole media box.
